# Enable the GPU acceleration model's color disappear

Tags: google-chrome, nvidia, cesiumjs, gltf

I created a model using CINEMA 4D which has some colors like green, gray, red..., and exported as obj format. Then I converted the obj file to gltf format file using obj2gltf tool, and load gltf file on Cesium like this:

```
var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-123.0744619, 44.0503706, height); 
var heading = Cesium.Math.toRadians(10000); 
var pitch = 0; 
var roll = 0; 
var hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, roll); 
var orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(position, hpr); 

entity = viewer.entities.add({ 
    name : url, 
    position : position, 
    orientation : orientation, 
    model : { 
        uri : url, 
        minimumPixelSize : 128, 
        maximumScale : 20000, 
    } 
}); 
viewer.trackedEntity = entity;
```

But on the Chrome browser, the model's color is completely black.

[image]

1. When I disabled the chrome GPU acceleration option,it is normal.
2. Then I checked my graphics card is NVIDIA Geforce GTX,but on another notebook compute with AMD graphics card, it works normally.
3. I tried some other obj file which size less than the  obj(about 44M),and they worked normally.
4. I tried other browser IE and Firefox, the result is the same as the chrome browser.

Did any body have the same problem? 
Please help me to issue it. 
Thanks very much and forgive my poor chinese english!

Comment: my gltf model url:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6u64RokzQalRzllSk1FRlczbEk

Comment: What time of day is it in your Cesium view?  Cesium keeps accurate time keeping, and if your model is on the night side of the planet, even though the terrain has day/night lighting disabled, the model might not be getting any sunlight.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't known how to set the time with code.I will try to set it later.I tried to use gltf-pipeline tool optimizing the light of model,but failed.

Comment: It has been solved by :https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum%2Fcesium-dev&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&hideforumtitle=true&fragments=true&parenturl=https%3A%2F%2Fcesiumjs.org%2Fforum%2F&afterlogin=#!topic/cesium-dev/eXxk3Oi0hEM

Answer (score 0):

Just copying [Sean's answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cesium-dev/eXxk3Oi0hEM/OSQKbBVaBAAJ) from the Cesium forum, so this question can be marked resolved:

> Since you are using obj2gltf, pass in --materialsCommon and the materials should show up correctly.